# Sonar security warning for Multer (Express.js)

Tags: node.js, security, sonarqube, multer

Our app has Sonarqube D.o.S. (Denial of service) warning being triggered, when using Multer for upload.

Sonarqube suggested to set 'limits' option for max content length(done).

But the .diskStorage line is still considered breaking that rule - why?

[image: see screenshot]

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "./uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const multipartUpload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 8_000_000, // Compliant: 8MB
    fieldSize: 8_000_000, // Compliant: 8MB
  },
}).fields([{ name: "file" }, { name: "document" }]);
```

Refactored as suggested in Sonar 'how to fix':

```
let diskUpload = multer({
  storage: diskStorage,
  limits: {
     fileSize: 8000000 // Compliant: 8MB
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you find a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Selam Getachew, no, but wrote it differently and sonar removed warning:


const upload = multer({
  dest: "./uploads/",
  limits: {
    fileSize: 7_000_000,
  },
});

....
app.post(`/documents`, upload.array("file"), createDoc);

Comment: @SergeySobolevsky , If you found out how to solve it, Could you answer your question? same issue here.